Crystal Report 13.0.2 Database Connection Error to SQLSERVER
I would appreciate it if you could enlighten us with your wisdom, as we're going crazy trying to find a solution to this issue. We are currently developing an ERP system in Visual Basic, using Visual Studio 2022 with .NET Framework 4.8. We have a reporting system with Crystal Reports, where all the DLLs are currently at version 13.0.200. However, we are encountering a "connection" issue when generating the latest reports.
We are getting exactly this error message:
-This is the error that we get randomly.

We have already tried:

Verifying if it’s a connection loss
We moved the server from LINUX to Windows; it is an SQL SERVER 2019
We tested different versions of Windows on the clients; it didn’t work on any of them
We installed the ODBC ADO drivers on all the test machines, and still nothing
From our edge firewall, we verified that the connection is not being cut
We also ran the ERP from the server itself to check if it’s not a connection issue, pointing to localhost from the report, and the same issue occurred
We recompiled the solution in Visual Studio with the same DLLs but new ones, so to speak (same version but freshly imported)
We recompiled with new DLLs, Crystal Decisions Reports 13.0.400; previously, we had 13.0.200
New ODBC connections in Crystal Reports Designer 2020

Additionally, we have read an impressive amount of forums and tested all possible solutions they suggested.
Considering that the ERP is a WINFORM and has its own connection string independent of CRYSTAL REPORT, we also tried pointing Crystal to the same connection string. Additionally, to top it off, the issue only occurs sometimes, not always.

You can try this: Crystal Report Asking for Login Credentials

Hi, I've already tried doing that item, but it didn't work out either.

Don't build NEW things in .Net 4.8, especially if you have access to VS2022. You'll save yourself a ton of trouble down the road. Sure, if you have an existing product you might keep in on 4.8 for now, but something new? Choosing 4.8 is nuts.

Also, that's NOT an error message. That's a connection dialog. You might see an actual error if you attempt to connect from this dialog, but it sounds like the application might be swallowing this exception, hiding the real error from you. And please tell me you're not actually using the sa account? That's terrible practice... would fail a pre-purchase security audit at most companies big enough to need an ERP.

What line of code is failing?
What is the error message?
What happens if you run the same rpt file on the same machine using Crystal Designer (or a Crystal Reports viewer)?

Hi, from the developers' machines, the report runs without any issue when pointing it towards the production server. No part of the code fails. That's the funny part—within the Crystal Report Designer 2020, it opens without any problem, and when updating the report, it loads perfectly fine. The strange thing is that from the ERP, it works on some computers but not on others. We've tried cloning the folders from the working machines onto the non-working ones, but it gives the same result. Additionally, for other reports, sometimes that message appears.

I guess the easiest way would be to install some 3rd party Crystal Viewer and check if it is working. If it is not working , the issue is in your ODBC connection or the access to the database server. If it is working then the issue is in your VB code. Here is a link to a Crystal viewer , which will not require purchase and you can use it to check your connection : RT Report Viewer
